# Where to store large deposit of images for a react application?

Tags: reactjs, database, image, filesystems

I am developing a React web application that will require a large amount of images to be loaded dynamically based on user interaction (e.g. the user clicks on a grid and loads a specific image).

The issue is that the application will have a large number of images (about 10000 in total) and some of them are quite large files (around 20mb - 40mb). We are expecting a total size of around 200gb - 400gb for all the images.

Where would be the best place to store these images? One option would be some sort of database (e.g. AWS), but I'm not sure how well that scales with such a large number of images.

Alternatively, would storing the images on the filesystem be a viable solution? I am currently not sure what the options are for deploying and hosting a site with such a large number of images.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will need a database, if you have a server machine you might serve it there or with a provider like you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally suggest to go with cloud storages.Storing in filesystems is not easily transferrable and also expensive.We also need to go over the security aspects which makes cloud platforms the better choice.They are also scalable,depending upon the service and provider you decide to go with.For me Dropbox is the best choice as it is cheaper and also almost cover all my required services.